# "dnf update" vs. "yum update" command differences in CentOS Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, centos8

Does anyone know what's the difference between the below command in CentOS Linux ?:

```
dnf update
yum update
```

Which one is better to use with Cron as automated OS update?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`yum` was replaced with `dnf` in CentOS 8. The command `yum` still exists because people will still remember it for years to come. The only thing it does is to call `dnf`.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -l /usr/bin/yum
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 5 Jul 21 18:46 /usr/bin/yum -> dnf-3
[root@localhost ~]# file /usr/bin/yum
/usr/bin/yum: symbolic link to dnf-3
```

Comment: Hi Mike, so in this case, it would be better to use dnf-3 command?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer You should use `dnf`, this is the canonical command. Here `dnf-3` means only that it is the version for Python 3. There was a Python 2 version early on that was named `dnf-2` but it was obsoleted before RHEL 8 release.

Comment: that's great, many thanks Mike !

Comment: Is this similar to the situation with `apt` and `apt-get` in Ubuntu (since 16.04 LTS, I believe)?

Comment: @wyphan Not exactly. `apt` and `apt-get` are subtly different. `dnf` entirely replaced `yum`.